# Cascading DropDownList GridView ObjectDataSource

Tags: ajax, gridview, objectdatasource, cascadingdropdown

my page contains cascading DDL and grid view which working pure ajax.
the GridView taking data from sqlDataSouce which apply stored procedure that taking the DDL's values as parameters.
when i select value in the DDL the grid view changes it's data without refreshing the whole page.

yesterday i had to change the stored procedure and for some reason the sqlDataSource start having problems getting the data.

so after many attempts to make it work i finally try using ObjectDataSource, which managed to run the stored procedure properly and get the data. but now when i select value in the DDL's i get Page Error and the GridView stays as is.

who can i make it work ? (i didn't find a satisfying answer when i searched)
Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 cascading Country and state DDL
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.CountryList, "--Select Country--", new { @class = "CountryList", style = "width:150px" })

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.StateList, "--Select State--", new { @class = "StateList", style = "width:150px" })

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.post("/Client/GetModels", { id: $(".CountryList").val() }, function (data) {
                populateDropdown($(".StateList"), data);
            });
            $(".CountryList").change(function () {
                $.post("/Client/GetModels", { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                    populateDropdown($(".StateList"), data);
                });
            });
        });

        function populateDropdown(select, data) {
            $(".StateList").empty();
            $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                $(".StateList").append("<option value='" + option.StateId + "'>" + option.State + "</option>");
            });
        }
    </script>
```